# IntelliJ stop formatting license header

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In a project with an Apache2 license header in every file IntelliJ started to reformat the license header (it adds some spaces and removes others), while this is not tragic, it's unnecessary and would create unnecessary changes in the version control. This happens when you run the `Reformat Code/Ctrl+Alt+L` command, the header gets modified, which it shouldn't.

I haven't found anyway to disable reformatting of license headers.

The issue started about 1-2 years ago. I have been using an old version of IntelliJ ever since, but due to a new laptop I  wanted to test the recent IntelliJ again, but it still shows this issue. Happens with community and enterprise edition.

Using Formatter Control is not a solution.

The weirdest thing is, usually regular formatting changes can be reversed easily within in the editor by simply pressing the reverse button, the change in the license header is not reversed for some reason, I always end up reversing it in git, which is quite annoying.

Comment: Sounds like you should just need to disable the formatting for Copyright notices: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/formatting.html

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, I even disabled the Copyright plugin with no success.

Comment: What does the reformat exactly change? If you have 3rd plugins for formatting, try with them disabled.

Comment: @Andrey, no 3rd party plugins installed, fresh install. The reformat just removes 1 or 2 spaces, and adds spaces at 1 or 2 places. That's not tragic, but it's an unnecessary change in version control.

Comment: sounds like the copyright headers defined in your project don't match those in your sourcefiles and IJ replaces them with the versions defined in the project.

Comment: @jwenting, I haven't defined anything in IJ and even tried to disable the copyright plugin. Haven't had any luck here. Are there any other details you could provide on how to do this?

Comment: @Robin if you have defined no copyright headers, IJ will treat them like any other comments and apply whatever formatting rules are defined for them.

Comment: Thanks @jwenting. I haven't setup any special formatting rules for comments and found no way to disable formatting comments at all. There is an option to disable formatting JavaDoc, but since the license is not in JavaDoc, this does not change the behavior at all. It is also weird that the changes in the license header are not reversible (`CTRL+Z`), regular formatting changes can be easily reversed, so I suspect the reason is something else.